# Conditional (dynamic) destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Depending on the selected language, I need to destruct the object and get the desired value.
How do I do this so as not to destruct the entire object?

```
const translate = {
   "navMenu1": {
      "en": "Menu 1",
      "ru": "Меню 1"
   },
   "navMenu2": {
      "en": "Menu 2",
      "ru": "Меню 2"
   },
   "navMenu3": {
      "en": "Menu 3",
      "ru": "Меню 3"
   }
}

const Header = props => {
  const { lang } = props;

  const {
    navMenu1,
    navMenu2,
    navMenu3
  } = translate;

  return (
    <header className={cnGreetingHeader}>
      <div>-Logo-</div>
      <nav className={cnNav}>
        <div className={cnItem}>{navMenu1[lang]}</div>
        <div className={cnItem}>{navMenu2[lang]}</div>
        <div className={cnItem}>{navMenu3[lang]}</div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};
```

I want instead

```
<div className={cnItem}>{navMenu1[lang]}</div>
```

Use

```
<div className={cnItem}>{navMenu1}</div>
```

**Important: I would like an answer that uses destructuring assignment, if possible.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a nested destructuring and take the outer name as variable.

```js
const
    translate = { navMenu1: { en: "Menu 1", ru: "Меню 1" }, navMenu2: { en: "Menu 2", ru: "Меню 2" }, navMenu3: { en: "Menu 3", ru: "Меню 3" } },
    Header = props => {
        const
            { lang } = props,
            {
                navMenu1: { [lang]: navMenu1 },
                navMenu2: { [lang]: navMenu2 },
                navMenu3: { [lang]: navMenu3 }
            } = translate;

        console.log(navMenu1);
        console.log(navMenu2);
        console.log(navMenu3);
    };

Header({ lang: 'en' });
```

Answer (score 5):

Altougth you asked destructing, you can just map the object values, its more scalable, what happens when you have much more nav items?

```
<nav className={cnNav}>
  {Object.values((navMenu) => (
    <div key={navMenu.id} className={cnItem}>
      {navMenu[lang]}
    </div>
  ))}
</nav>
```